# Speeding up a rolling sum calculation?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I'm doing some work with a fairly large amount of (horse racing!) data for a project, calculating rolling sums of values for various different combinations of data - thus I need to streamline it as much as possible.

Essentially I am:

- calculating the rolling calculation of a points field over time
- calculating this for various grouped combinations of data [in this case the combination of horse and trainer]
- looking at the average of the value by group for the last 180 days of data through time

The rolling window calculation below works fine - but takes 8.2s [this is about 1/8 of the total dataset - hence would take 1m 5s]. I am looking for ideas of how to streamline this calculation as I'm looking to do it for a number of different combinations of data, and thus speed is of the essence. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/richsdixon/testdata/main/testdata.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=True)

df['RaceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RaceDate'], format='mixed')
df.sort_values(by='RaceDate', inplace=True)
df['HorseRaceCount90d'] = (df.groupby(['Horse','Trainer'], group_keys=False)
                                 .apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window='180D', on='RaceDate', min_periods=1)['Points'].mean()))
```

Comment: Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and [mre] then edit your post.

Comment: I was hoping that in providing a subset of the data I was using that it provided enough of a reproducable example here.

Comment: How fast, specifically is acceptable vs unacceptable? Is taking 8.0s acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little faster way:

```
df.merge(df.set_index('RaceDate')
           .groupby(['Horse', 'Trainer'])['Points']
           .rolling('180D')
           .mean()
           .rename('HorseRaceCount90d_1'), 
         right_index=True, 
         left_on=['Horse', 'Trainer', 'RaceDate'])
```

Your way:

> 18.5 s ± 727 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

This way:

> 1.18 s ± 36.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Quick Comparison:

```
       RaceID   RaceDate               Horse           Jockey            Trainer  Points  HorseRaceCount90d  HorseRaceCount90d_1
0      678365 2017-01-08        STRADIVARIUS    Andrea Atzeni        John Gosden  100.00         100.000000           100.000000
289    680610 2017-01-08      CLASSIC PALACE     Brian Hughes       Dianne Sayer    1.76           1.760000             1.760000
288    680610 2017-01-08       ROMAN NUMERAL     Joe Colliver     David Thompson    0.00           0.000000             0.000000
287    680610 2017-01-08     COOPER'S FRIEND  Conor O'Farrell       R Mike Smith    0.00           0.000000             0.000000
286    680610 2017-01-08  GLEANN NA NDOCHAIS     Craig Nichol  Alistair Whillans    0.00           0.000000             0.000000
...       ...        ...                 ...              ...                ...     ...                ...                  ...
96817  702712 2018-12-06          URBAN ICON     Tom Marquand     Richard Hannon   12.50          12.500000            12.500000
96816  702712 2018-12-06           EVEN KEEL       Rob Hornby   Jonathan Portman   11.07          11.070000            11.070000
96815  702712 2018-12-06         MOLLY BLAKE    Hector Crouch          Clive Cox    9.73           9.730000             9.730000
96885  702719 2018-12-06      CELTIC ARTISAN       Cam Hardie    Rebecca Menzies    2.37           1.046667             1.046667
97076  704968 2018-12-06             REVENGE      David Allan       Tim Easterby    2.47           1.346667             1.346667

[100008 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I hope this example can stay here just to show how relatively inefficient some calculations can be.

Comment: @RichardDixon FYI... You are 'apply'ing that rolling lambda function all all columns except for 'Horse' and 'Trainer', then you are only selecting the points column.   This is where most of your inefficiencies are coming from.  Here, we are grouping only the Points column and rolling on those groups.

Comment: Thanks - I'm a relative novice so this is good to know - the actual database has 30+ columns so I assume the gains will be more for the wider database.